# Vertically aligning an a tag in an li tag with dynamic height

Tags: css

I have a div `offers` that is dynamically sized, and then inside 6 li tags that each have 16.6% height to fill up the div. Inside each `li` tag is an `a` tag, but I want to **vertically align** the `a` tag. I have looked at a lot of different solutions and none of them seem to be working for me. An example of my code is;

```css
.offers {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
.offers li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 16.6%;
  width: 100%
}
.offers li a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="offers">
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link6</a></li> 
</div>
```

Here is a codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXXJEY

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/oLLEXb

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWWyap

Comment: @PascalGoldbach vertically but not horizontally.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `li` MUST be children of `ul/ol`...not a `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use display table cell, replace your css in the codepen with the following and it should work:

```
.offers {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:200px;
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
}
.offers li {
  display:table-row;
}
.offers li a {
  background-color:red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: The li {display:table-row;} was what was missing! This answer seems to be the most cross-browser and also the most similar to my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tables you can use `Flexbox`

1. You can use `flex-direction: column` on `.offers` and `flex: 1` on `li` to make each `li` evenly spaced instead of using `%`
2. You can use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on each `li` to make `a` vertically centered

```css
.offers {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}
.offers li {
  border: solid 1px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.offers li a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="offers">
  <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display:flex; on the li element. After that put align-items:center; on it.

Use prefixes for crossbrowser compatibillity.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css.

```
.offers li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
}
.offers li a {
  background-color:red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/afelixj/pen/ezzVNX

Answer (score 0):

```css
.offers {background-color:yellow;height:200px;}
.offers li {
  vertical-align:middle; border:solid 1px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:33.33px;
  width:100%
}
.offers li a {
  background-color:red; 
  line-height: 33.33px;
}
.offers li a span {line-height: 1em;}
```

```html
<div class="offers">
  <li><a href="#"><span>Link1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link4</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link5</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link6</span></a></li>
</div>
```